# How to get the sum of two cells in multiple columns for each record of a table in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I have table:

[image: Table]

I was able to get the column values with my laravel controller, I just want to know how am I to calculate the total of each row.

I am fairly new to Laravel.

```
   $posts = DB::table('posts')->select('id', 'col_a', 'col_b','col_c')->get();
   return view('mainview')->with('posts', $posts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `total` is registered column on your table, then the calculate process should be placed just before the data is saved. You could try using built in laravel [event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events) `saving` (triggered before saving to database).

On your model, create `boot()` method

```php
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

       /**
         * We calculate the column $total automatically every time
         * we call the $model->save();
         */
        self::saving(function($model){
            $model->total = $model->col_a + $model->col_b + $model->col_c;
        });

    }
```

Or you could override the `save()` function on your model

```php
    /**
     * Override the Save function
     *
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function save(array $options = [])
    {
        $this->total = $this->col_a + $this->col_b + $this->col_c;
        return parent::save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = Post::all();
```

In the related Model

```
    public function getTotal(){
     return $this->col_a + $this->col_b + $this->col_c;
}
```

I assume you are using foreach loop in the blade.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    Total: {{ $post->getTotal()
@endforeach
```

Didn't tested but this is one simple logic to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much Ali..I will try this out.